# Why is std::cout automatically flushing?

Tags: c++

Why is my `cout` automatically flushing in the given code? There is no `endl` or `end` or `flush` command given, so what is making my `cout` flush before the `Sleep()` command? I am expecting for the `cout` to flush after the `Sleep()` command.

I tried to create a very simple program to test when `cout` was flushing. From what I understand, `cout` should not flush until after the `Sleep()` command in the below code. What actually happens is that `cout` prints to the console and then the `Sleep()` command runs.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    std::cout << "test";
    Sleep(30000);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout` is not *required* to buffer its output, but in common implementations it *may* buffer. You did not provide any details about your environment, so any answer is just speculation about why your `cout` output is flushing.

Comment: Try to trace the code. You will see where does it flush.

Comment: Here are some reasons why `cout` would flush:  1) Internal buffers are near full. 2) The `endl` is used.  3) The `flush()` method is called.  3) The stream switched (like `cout` to `cerr`). 4) Error handling / recovery.  5) Program execution finished.

Comment: Related  (in fact, virtually identical, but with no answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66198413/is-stream-flushing-implemented-in-windows-h-sleepx